# How do I sort two converged lists by datetime?

Tags: python, django

I have converged two different lists. How do I sort them by date/time?

```
foo = get_list_or_404(Comments, equoes=user) 
foo2 = get_list_or_404(Comments, User=user) 
info = (foo+foo2) 
for x in info: 
print(x.dt)
```

### (Edit: answered my own question:  info = sorted(info, key=lambda time: time.dt))

Everything I am looking for comes up in the printout, but I need to sort it by time. How would I go about this?

(This is how it prints, the last two being from the added list.)

```
2019-05-03 17:12:55.611679+00:00
2019-05-03 17:58:08.319295+00:00
2019-05-03 18:13:19.608188+00:00
2019-05-03 15:06:43.242201+00:00
2019-05-03 14:47:19.166391+00:00
```

Comment: For future reference, you can answer and accept your own answer below.

Answer (score 1):

**`foo`** and **`foo2`** are ***`Queryset`*** of **`Comments`**(/of same Model) model. So, you could use [**`order_by()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) method of queryset

```
info.order_by('dt')
```

where **`dt`** is the date or datetime field